# Trying to capture image from camera and display it in imageview but getting error. how to capture the image and display it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I click the button it opens the camera then i click the camera to take a photo then click on the OK it's back to the application but not showing anything in the imageview.  it should show in the imageview the taken photo from the camera. instead, it's throwing error in the logcat.

main activity xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openCameraButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
        android:text="Open Camera"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/capturedImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

mainactivity kt

```
    package com.example.lightningsdetection

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Locale

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var capturedImageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        capturedImageView = findViewById(R.id.capturedImageView)

        val openCameraButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.openCameraButton)
        openCameraButton.setOnClickListener {
                openCamera()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        val imageUri = data?.data
        if (imageUri != null) {
            // Display the captured image
            displayCapturedImage(imageUri)
        }
    }

    private fun displayCapturedImage(imageUri: Uri) {
        capturedImageView.setImageURI(imageUri)
    }

    // Open the camera using an Intent
    private fun openCamera() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            // Handle the case where no camera app is available
        }
    }
}
```

the manifest xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LightningsDetection"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Add other activities, services, etc. here -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The error getting in the logcat:

> win=Window{44002c0 u0 com.example.lightningsdetection/com.example.lightningsdetection.MainActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true cleanupOnResume=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6539 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6520 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:6584 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:7172 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:258 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:613 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:136

Comment: https://github.com/KishanViramgama/LoginRegister check the register activity

Answer (score 0):

To capture an image and get the result, you need to use **startActivityForResult** instead of **startActivity**

For reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-open-camera-through-intent-and-display-captured-image-in-android/

Comment: I saw the startActivityForResult before but there is a black line over it.  what is the black line meaning?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).